# memory error in library linear_kernel to make cosine_similarities

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, content-based-retrieval

i have data set that contain 8 columns with 1482531 rows for every column 
i try to make content based rcomondation system by
making cosine similarities using linear_kernel in python 
but after half of hour it till me error memory 
are this due to large of data set , and if that is their a solution to solve this issue

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/data2/train.tsv',sep='\t', low_memory=False)

tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=0, stop_words='english')

dataset['item_description'] = dataset['item_description'].fillna('')

tfidf_matrix.shape
((1482535, 13831759))

cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

Comment: were u able to find the solution?

Comment: any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If your system has enough computational power, you can try the following method. Divide the data into chunks and write it to csv file(or db) and later use that file for prediction. Here is an small example if you have 1,00,000 records(say).

```
import csv
with open('cosine_data_test.csv','a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    i=0
    while i!=tfidf_matrix.shape[0]:
        if i%100000!=0:
            #Iterating over 10,000 multiples(10 chunks)
            cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix[i:i+1000], tfidf_matrix)
            print("{} completed".format(i+1000))
            writer.writerows(cosine_sim)
            i= i + 10000
```